# Simple way to spawn external process

Tags: javascript, php, web, cgi

I am facing a rather easy(?) problem, thought might be overwhelming for the webdev noob! I would like through Websocket or a similar API similar to send requests to my server running HTTP and that will act as a trigger for more process server side. To make this question more specific:

Let's say I wanna run a simple C++ process with one (or more) arguments on my server but:

a) ideally the argument will be appended on the url:

eg. localhost:12345/index.html?var=Joe

b) server will catch Joe and run the compiled binary originating from helloworld.cpp and reply the status to client,e.g. "Server has run hello world, Joe".

I am sure there are many ways to achieve this, but I'd like a simple workflow, e.g. CGI?

2) I think the server hosting HTTP might (should?) act just as a gateway between the client and the other machine running the C++ code.

I have looked into many web APIs, flask, websockd etc. but all require some sort of scripting language as a middleman.

I wouldnt want someone to bother implementing all this, I am quite certain if you know where to look a simple tutorial (or a mix of couple) could provide me with a minimal working example.

Could anyone suggest a similar howto?

Comment: There are things like `exec()` and `shell_exec()` but should be used with sanitized user inputs. Something like those?

Comment: @frz3993 which languages do you refer to?